# Read a value from an array

Tags: perl, ldap

I have an array defined as below.

I am able to fetch the value for `email` and `uid` as mentioned below. How do I get the *user display name* `userdn`?

```
my ($mesg) = $ldap->search(
    scope  => 'one',
    base   => $userdn,
    filter => $filter,
    attrs  => [ 'email', 'pwdChangedTime', 'uid' ],
);
```

This is how I read the email ID and uid, but I'm unable to read the user display name.

```
foreach my $entry ( $mesg->all_entries ) {

    $email = ${ $entry->get( 'email' ) }[0];
    $uid   = ${ $entry->get( 'uid' ) }[0];
    $uName = ${ $entry->get( 'userdn' ) };
}
```

Comment: Please explain what `$ldap` is. How did you define it?

Answer (score 4):

This is not really about an array, but rather about how to use [`Net::LDAP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP). There are no arrays in your example code.

You want to get the *userdn* property for the items returned from your LDAP query. In order to do that, you need to [tell `search` to fetch those](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod#attrs-=%3E-[-ATTR,-...-]).

> A list of attributes to be returned for each entry that matches the search filter.

This means, you need to include *userdn* in the call to `search`.

```
my ($mesg) = $ldap->search(
    scope  => 'one',
    base   => $userdn,
    filter => $filter,
    attrs  => [ 'email', 'pwdChangedTime', 'uid', 'userdn' ],
);
```

Now you can `get` the *userdn*.

```
$uName = $entry->get('userdn')->[0];
```

I've used the arrow dereference syntax instead of `${ ... }[0]` here because I find that easier to read. However, [as ysth points out below in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100418/read-the-vaue-from-array-in-perl/44100516?noredirect=1#comment75221932_44100516), `get` is deprecated and not documented in the current version of `Net::LDAP`. It [was deprecated](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/perl-ldap#L660) in release 0.21 in September 2000, which is currently seventeen years ago.

Instead, you should probably use [`get_value`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP::Entry#get_value-(-ATTR,-OPTIONS-)), which returns the first value of that attribute.

```
$uName = $entry->get_value('userdn');
```

Comment: `${$entry->get('uid')}[0]` sure looks like an array to me

Comment: @ysth looks like an array reference ;)

Comment: from the code (get is deprecated and doesn't seem to be documented), it looks like get will return an array reference in scalar context and a list in list context.  so either an array slice or a list slice is needed.  or use get_value instead.

Comment: @ysth yeah I found it. It has only been deprecated for about half of my life... somehow that frightens me.

Comment: There are no references to any resources that are mentioned here. I haven't searched myself, but I would like to see a link to "from the code (get is deprecated and doesn't seem to be documented)" from @ysth and any documentation at all for `get` or `get_all`. I would also like to know how you can be certain that the OP is using `Net::LDAP` on what seems to be the basis of a variable identifier `$ldap`. I have added a link to `Net::LDAP` to your answer. Is that all that is required?

Comment: I would also like to understand why you don't advocate fetching all of what seems to be a list, with `my @uNames = $entry->get('userdn')`. It may be that the module was written with a mistaken expectation that there may be multiple results,. but the name of the `get_all` method suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Borodin where are you seeing get_all (rather than get orvget_value) mentioned?  I was looking at http://p3rl.org/Net::LDAP::Entry

Comment: @ysth: [you wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100418/read-a-value-from-array/44100516?noredirect=1#comment75221932_44100516) *"or use `get_value` instead"*. Ah, I see. You didn't mean `orvget_value` and I didn't mean `get_all`. Problem solved. But the core of my comments is that there are no hyperlinks. There are none still.

Comment: @Borodin I provided the hyperlinks that ysth was talking about when I updated my answer. I was looking at the same thing at the same time. I deducted that it's Net::LDAP from the way the code looked. The `$ldap` was a pointer, but the rest of the syntax looked familiar. I didn't suggest to fetch all the values because to me it looked like the OP wanted only the first, hence the `[0]`. And on the _userdn_ line where it's a scalar deref I assumed a typo.